# Why do I get an error message about images?

Tags: support, asking-questions, error-message

I am trying to post a question, but always getting below error message. I really don't understand the issue because I am not including or attaching any images but still I am getting the error message.

Apart from that, the worst part is that I can't cancel the question and go and ask a question from the start, again and again, I am getting the same question content where I left off due to the above-mentioned error.

> Oops! Your question couldn't be
>   submitted because:
>
> we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't
>   allowed to post images. Earn more than
>   10 reputation to post images.

Comment: Strange. Can you show the content you are trying to post?

Answer (score 5):

Well you managed to post this question ;). There must be a url in your post somewhere that is being interpreted as an image.

Without the actual contents of your post (which you won't be able to post!) it's going to be difficult to diagnose what's wrong.

The system saves a draft of your post which is why you are seeing it when you leave and come back.

Comment: yes you are right, i had some image url. Thanks a lot for the help :)